# Pytest - Can multiple tests share same request response?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a list of url pairs, and I created this parametrized test for them:

```
url_list = [
    ['example1.com/x', 'example2.com/x'],
    ['example1.com/y', 'example2.com/y'],
    ['example1.com/z', 'example2.com/z'],
    ['example1.com/v', 'example2.com/v'],
    ['example1.com/w', 'example2.com/w'],
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('url1, url2', url_list)
def test_urls(url1: str, url2: str):
    response1 = requests.get(url1)
    response2 = requests.get(url2)

    assert response1.status_code == response2.status_code

    body1 = response1.json()
    body2 = response2.json()

    for field in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
        assert body1[field] == body2[field]
```

The problem is that if the value for `'one'` is bad, we don't test values for `'two'` and `'three'`.

I was thinking about adding another parametrization, something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('field', ['one', 'two', 'three'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('url1, url2', url_list)
def test_urls(url1: str, url2: str):
    response1 = requests.get(url1)
    response2 = requests.get(url2)

    assert response1.status_code == response2.status_code

    body1 = response1.json()
    body2 = response2.json()

    assert body1[field] == body2[field]
```

The problem with that is that the same request will be performed multiple times.

I could use global variables that would store the request responses between tests, but that feels ugly.

Is there anything within pytest that would help me?

Or a design pattern / a pythonic way of doing this?

I've been using python for a few years, but this is my first time using pytest.

Comment: If your goal is just to _see_ the full output if an assertion fails, you can do something like `assert body1[field] == body2[field], f"{body1} != {body2}"`

Comment: That won't give me the ability to easily see which tests failed for field `'one'`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by using [fixture scopes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session):

> Fixtures are created when first requested by a test, and are destroyed based on their scope

Normal fixtures have a function scope, but if you want to reuse the fixture values within the same file, `scope="module"` or scope="class" might be most appropriate, but other options are possible.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def response1():
    yield requests.get(url1)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def response2():
    yield requests.get(url2)

def test_responses1(response1, response2):
    assert response1.status_code == response2.status_code

@pytest.mark.parametrize("field", ["one", "two", "three"])
def test_responses2(field, response1, response2):
    body1 = response1.json()
    body2 = response2.json()
    assert body1[field] == body2[field]
```

To verify that each fixture is only called once, you can run pytest with `-s` and print some value within each fixture. Ie. rewrite `response1`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def response1():
    print("in response1")
    yield requests.get(url1)
```

then run `pytest -s` on your tests

**EDIT**:
If the urls always come in pairs I would rewrite the code in the following way:

```py
url_pairs = [('url1a', 'url1b'), ('url2a', 'url2b')]

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=url_pairs)
def response_pairs(request):
    url_a, url_b = request.param
    yield requests.get(url_a), requests.get(url_b)

def test_responses1(response_pairs):
    response_a, response_b = response_pairs
    assert response_a.status_code == response_b.status_code

@pytest.mark.parametrize("field", ["one", "two", "three"])
def test_responses2(field, response_pairs):
    body_a = response_pairs[0].json()
    body_b = response_pairs[1].json()
    assert body_a[field] == body_b[field]
```

Comment: url1 and url2 come from a list of pairs, and I wand all those actions performed on each pair of urls

Comment: @eternal_student Is the edit I made what you were looking for?

Comment: I think so... Do `test_response1` and `test_response2` each get all the pairs? and each url gets called only once?

Comment: @eternal_student tldr: yes. Long answer: `request.get` will only be called once per url, so for the example above 4 times, no matter how many test functions are defined which use `response_pairs`. `response_pairs` will contain a tuple of 2 responses. `test_responses1` will be called twice, once for each pair of urls, while `test_responses2` will be called 6 times, 2 url pairs each combined with 3 field values.

Comment: I tried your example yesterday, and I was pleasantly surprised. I thought fixtures work like generators and that two tests calling the same generator... I'm loving Pytest more and more!